# python the limit of multiprocessing.pool doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When i use the multiprocessing.pool to do a research in quantitative strategy, there is a problem occurred in the linux server monitor with htop. It seems that the parameters processes doesn't work and all cpus are occupied.
For example, if i set multiprocessing.pool(processes=8) and use pool.apply_async to run my backtest strategy with parameters' length 6000. It seems everything is right at the beginning of the backtest and after some time, it shows that all 24 cpus are occupied by this program, it seems that processes=8 doesn't work.
Pseudo code like this:

```
def stragegy(paras):
    # some trading logic
    return indicator
if __name == '__main__':
    # paras_list has 6000 different parameters
    # a_list: store the result of strategy
    paras_list = [[..], [..], ...[..]]
    a_list = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)  # create 8 processes
    for i in range(len(paras_list)):
        a_list.append(pool.apply_async(func=strategy, args=(paras_list[i])))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

[linux server -htop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxmYI.png)

Is anyone can help me about this problem?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you run the `strategy` function in a single process (remove the pool logic), how many processes get started? What libraries and frameworks are you using?

Comment: @noxdafox In this situation, there will only one single process started. In my multiprocessing program, it seems everything is right at the first, then after about 50 parameters backtest finished, the cpu resources are all occupied suddenly.

Comment: @noxdafox I use the pandas, numpy, multiprocessing, os and time libraries in my code.